# Blender .dae and .stl files not importing with textures and particles in the right place

Tags: import, dae

I am trying to import .dae and .stl files into Blender but they are not importing with textures or particles in the right places. I have included screenshots of the actual model and how the .stl and .dae files import, respectively. I am looking to import the tree model into Gazebo to run simulations. I would appreciate any help I can get!

[image][image][image]